# Setup two SSLs for different subdomains with same document root

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, subdomain

I have this directories:

```
 /var/www/domain.com/web/domains/example.com
 /var/www/domain.com/web/domains/cdn.example.com
 /var/www/domain.com/web/domains/app.example.com
```

It means, that I don't specify each website subdomain, but I just create subdomain in this directory and my .htaccess will take care about this.

Now I'm solving this problem - I have SSL certificate for domain app.example.com but I also need to set SSL for cdn.example.com and I don't know, how to set it up. I tried to generate SSL certificate for cdn.example.com but I'm not able to set it for cdn.example.com -> if I try this:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect cdn.example.com:443 2>/dev/null
```

I still see, that certificate subject is `app.example.com` instead of `cdn.example.com`, so I think, it is still trying to get bad certificate for this domain.

Directories to SSLs are correct. Do you see any fail in my `example.com.vhost` file?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/web

        ServerName app.example.com
        ServerAlias app.example.com

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/clients/client1/web17/ssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/clients/client1/web17/ssl/example.com.key
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/web

        ServerName cdn.example.com
        ServerAlias cdn.example.com

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/clients/client1/web17/ssl/cdn/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/clients/client1/web17/ssl/cdn/server.key
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing SSL without the servername identifier. To have more than one SSL certificate per IP, your clients will need to use the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension.

So to test with OpenSSL, you need to set `-servername`. Your command will then be:

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername cdn.website.com -connect cdn.website.com:443
```

Comment: Thank you.It is working now but if I sudomain online, there is now lock icon, indicating, that there is SSL certificate used. Do you know why? Is it caused, because the certificate is self-signed or there is any other problem?

Comment: @JanKožušník If it's self-signed certificate, that's the most likely problem yes; you could search around for your OS on how to add your certificate to the keystore. In any case, you can [view the certificate info](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/137295) in your browser to see what set off any alarms. :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Iskar. You wrote about SNI extension, that browsers need to have. As I looked at the link you post, it is supported by almost every browser. Does it mean, that I don't have to be afraid about this and it should work almost everywhere?

Comment: I looked at cdn.website.com in chrome and it shows me, that connection with this website is unsecure. So do you think, buying real certificate should fix this problem?

Comment: @JanKožušník all recent OSes and browsers support it, yeah. Unless you have a lot of users on WinXP with IE6, it should be okay. And I don't know your error message, but assuming it's "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID", then yes buying a certificate from a trusted CA would resolve that.

Comment: the SNI extension has been with us for very long, not that I want to unanswer an answer marked as valid, but I doubt any current client is missing SNI support nowadays. What he is clearly missing in that Apache config to have SNI working in Apache 2.2 is the NameVirtualhost directive (note this directive is specific for Apache 2.2, the latest version does not need it, that is, 2.4)

Comment: @ezra-s smart thinking! I don't use Apache much so I am not aware if that part mattered. But he was using s_client without the servername directive, which effectively becomes "test without SNI". The output he should have from my command (with -servername) would show if that Apache config change is needed or not, with him reading the results.

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache 2.2. You need the directive NameVirtualHost to specify different virtualhosts which share the same IP.

What you seem to be missing from the config you copy-pasted is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Define this one just once, and Apache 2.2 will know for which virtualhost each request should be delivered according to the Host header requested.